# Rails 5 app on EC2 keeps shutting down every few days.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

We upgraded form a t2.micro to a t2.small EC2 instance when I noticed Rails app was shutting down, and I'd have to restart Unicorn.

Since EC2 doesn't include memory utilization out of the box, I installed perl scripts per AWS docs, and see that we hit 87% memory utilization in the last hour, even though we have a tiny amount of traffic.

What are the main issues that could be causing this?

Comment: from your script, do you monitor the process ? are you sure rails process is using 87% memory or do you have any other process running ?

Comment: I have been scouring online, not sure if or how to view memory utilization by process on EC2.

Comment: `ps aux` would be a good start and tell you which process consumes most of the CPU/memory

Comment: great!  so looks like we have 1 unicorn master and 2 unicorn workers consuming 5% of avail memory each. -- not really indicating any issues.